# Liferay Display Page: can I have a private one AND a public one?

Tags: liferay, liferay-7

For a given Web Content, I can choose a private Display Page. Or a public one.

[image]
[image]

**Question**: Is there any way to have a private Display Page AND a private Display Page?

- The private one would be displayed to users who belong to the site.
- The public one would be displayed to the others.

If I understand correctly the Display Page is referenced by its `classUuid` being stored as the `layoutUuid` field in the `JournalArticle` table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. There's exactly one display page per article.
However, you can build that one page with dynamic content, so that people see different content based on their identity (e.g. by using Asset Publisher or even a custom Web Content Display portlet, where you can configure multiple articles for the portlets "surrounding" the displayed article in question.